# Separating a cell by first occurrence of a number

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, I have a bunch of cells like this:

```
Freddie’s Restaurant 102 Super Lane San Diego California
```

and I want to pull out the name, which is always preceding the start of the address (102 Super...). Is there any way I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is that always two words in all cases like "Freddie’s Restaurant" ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. It will be a different name with different combinations of words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in **A1** use:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,1,MIN(IF(ISERROR(FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1)),"",FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1)))-1))
```

**EDIT#1:**

To get the "rest of the data" use:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,MIN(IF(ISERROR(FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1)),"",FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1))),9999))
```

Comment: Is there any way I can then get the rest of the cell into another? For this example, I need `102 Super Lane San Diego California` Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @user1282637  Yes.........see my **EDIT#1**